# How to switch from AsyncTask to OkHTTP, the ideal way?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

Haven't explored `OkHttp` previously, the network call using `AsyncTask` works fine at the moment, but would like to switch to `OkHttp` for other requirements,

Here's how I do the network call using `AsyncTask` :

```
   private class HTTPAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            try {
                return HttpPost(urls[0]);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("data is being sent",result);
    }
}
private String HttpPost(String myUrl) throws IOException {
    String result = "";

    URL url = new URL(myUrl);

    // 1. create HttpURLConnection
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(StringData);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    // 4. make POST request to the given URL
    conn.connect();

    // 5. return response message
    return conn.getResponseMessage()+"";

}
```

Now, how to perform the same `POST` call with `OkHttp` , here's where I am :

```
private void makeNetworkCall()
{
    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    Request request=new Request.Builder().url(post_url).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e)
        {

            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception parsing JSON", e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            Log.e("TAG","SUCCESS");
        }
    });
}
```

However, uncertain how to pass the data using the `OkHttp` way, Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanking you.

Comment: I think you are confused about what both AsyncTask and OkHttp do but they are not mutually exclusive. You should read more about both of them to understand. Your example doesn't even show an AsyncTask.

Comment: @RobertoBetancourt See the edited code !

Answer (score 0):

Honesty, I would not even bother with plain OkHttp [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) is your tools of choice, it's quite versatile (even supports Rx-like style) and eases out a lot of low-level stuff you have to deal with right now.

To even more advance your skills, take a look at [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer in that Retrofit would probably be better in the long run if you plan on making a lot of different network calls to a backend. But if you insist on using OkHttp at a lower level then you can do something like this:

```
String jsonString = json.toString();
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonString);

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    .url(post_url)
    .post(body)
    .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new com.squareup.okhttp.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

    }
});
```